# PHP compare values from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

The MySql table looks like:

```
    id    |        values   
  --------------------------------
    41    |    154, 256, 526, 50
    86    |    542, 586, 785, 41
```

I want to compare values ​​from this database with values ​​from results from another MySql query.
From that another query I get result for specific user and valus, for example:

```
user id: 41
values: 154,526,50
```

How can I compare this two database "values" columns and get as a result number of total different values ​​and the values ​​that are different?

In this example the result of that PHP function will be:

```
total number of different values: 1
different value: 256
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://WhatHaveYouTried.com)

Comment: Did you try exploding both fields and comparing arrays?

Answer (score 3):

By normalising your database. Save those values in a different table and create a new couplings table, connecting the values to the user. This will ease your development dramatically.

EDIT:
The query would then look like this:

```
SELECT
    value
FROM
    couplings_table
WHERE
    user_id = X
AND
    value NOT IN (SELECT
                    value
                  FROM
                    couplings_table
                  WHERE
                    user_id = Y)
```

Comment: Please show what the query would look like in a normalized database design.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_diff:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 1):

explode with "," and use array diff or search every item in_array and use results. I think array_diff is just for this.